# Does the Raspberry Pi 1 Model A support 128 GB SD cards?

Tags: boot

I am planning to expand my memory capacity to 128 GB. Are 128 GB cards supported by the Raspberry Pi 1 Model A?

Answer (score 1):

According to [eLinux](https://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) 128 GB SDXC cards have been successfully tested by individuals. But not all cards seemed to be working.

Entries with "Card Type" SDXC can only be used with RPi 1 Model A and B. All other models use microSDCX.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this site: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/4rxx22/128gb_sd_cards_that_work_with_pi3/ . It should help you find the information you need.